# PHP-FPM stalls if one thread times out

Tags: php-fpm

I've noticed this for a while, PHP-FPM works perfectly until one thread stalls.

For example if it takes too long to connect to another server or to process a database request all threads will stop responding to requests.

PHP-FPM will still be running and after about 1 minute will start responding to requests again.

It just seems to lock up.

Any idea what might be causing this?

It happens with a standard configuration running through a socket or a more customized configuration. Server load is irrelevant when it happens.

Doesn't matter if I use nginx or apache.